# openstack java programming

Tags: java, openstack

I am new to openstack and I am wondering what can you do with the java openstack API, what are practical applications the API is being used. Is the API used for batch job, is it being to create public interfaces like AWS, if examples could be pointed I would appreciate it, thank you for your help

Comment: You question is slightly too broad.  What are you trying achieve?

Comment: I guess I am asking can the java api be used to create a front end, like AWS, to enable end users to provision their own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a bunch of [examples](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/rackspace) of using jclouds on the Rackspace cloud powered by OpenStack.